# Use a string variable in MFMailCopose Message

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 - (IBAction)sendButton:(id)sender {

NSString *locationFormatter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=%f,%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Google Maps Directions"];
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:@[@"castro.michael87@gmail.com"]];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Google Maps Url:locationFormatter" isHTML:NO];

    // Display Mail Composer
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

How do I insert the locationFormatter string in the MessageBody?
I was hoping this would work:

```
[mailComposer setMessageBody:@"%@",locationFormatter isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: Use `NSString` `stringWithFormat:` : `[mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locationFormatter] isHTML:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[mailComposer setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Google Maps Url:%@", locationFormatter] isHTML:NO];
```